# How to open a form as ShowDialog(); the first time I am opening form but Show(); the second time I am opening the same form

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

```
Forms.inDepthScootForm.passProductDetails(strProductName, strProductDescription);
   
Forms.inDepthScootForm.ShowDialog();

Forms.eScootForm.Hide();
```

I am trying to open inDepthScootForm and hide/close eScootForm. I'm trying to open this form as a ShowDialog(); the first time I open it but as Show(); for subsequent times I open this form.

If I follow this method, the system will crash the second time I open the form.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You will have to say what error you got and show the code tat caused it

Comment: 'Form that is already displayed modally cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Close the form before calling showDialog.'   -- this is the error

Comment: I'm trying to code Show(); for the second time the form is opened but this error keeps popping up

Comment: Hi Nicholas, please be a bit more specific in your question, which one of the windows are you trying to open twice? Your code here doesn't show much, are these lines in eScootForm? Why are you using statics/globals instead of local variable windows etc.

So is inDepthScootForm being called twice? or is it eScootForm?

Please give us a minimum code to reproduce the error.
Cheers, Slipoch

Answer (score 0):

ShowDialog will only return to your function once it has been closed, so the hide function is being called after the show dialog is closed/finished.

First maybe create it as a `new` object, that way each instance of the form is unique *(assuming you do not want to keep the data on it)*, then make sure it is closed and disposed once you are finished with it. This should fix the Error of the window already being open.

So first hide your first form, then display the one you wish to display. If you use a using here then if the showdialog throws an exception it will still dispose of it.

```
using(var win = new Forms.inDepthScootForm())) {
    win.passProductDetails(strProductName, strProductDescription);
    Forms.eScootForm.Hide();
    win.ShowDialog();
} //win gets disposed as soon as the program leaves this

Forms.eScootForm.Show();
```

If this is not what you want, please be specific, ie: "When I show x window the second time I want it as a show, not a showdialog" but if you do, please make sure you show us the parent which is actually calling this window and is open while you do this.

Could you please edit your question to include the line and what window it is in that throws the error please?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you have the same instance of your 'eScootForm'. Maybe try to have a new instance when you show and dispose it when the dialog is closed as the example below :

```
public void ShowMyDialogBox()
{
   var testDialog = new Form2();

   // Show Form2 as a modal dialog
   testDialog.ShowDialog(this);

   // Do things when the dialog is closed
   this.txtResult.Text = testDialog.TextBox1.Text;

   // then dispose it
   testDialog.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: public void launchForm()
        {
            //Declare a variable of data type inDepthBikeForm
            //IndepthScootForm is a new class type created earlier
            //Display the new form
            //Close the current form
            Forms.inDepthScootForm.passProductDetails(strProductName, strProductDescription);

            Forms.eScootForm.Dispose();

            

            Forms.inDepthScootForm.Show();

            Forms.eScootForm.Hide();

        }

Comment: Sorry, i don't quite get your method. i would like to open the form as a Show(); the second but as ShowDialog(); the first time. Is there a way i can use looping or if to achieve this?

Comment: if you Dispose your eScootForm you can't use it after. You need to call your things in order //Forms.inDepthScootFrom = new ... //Forms.inDepthScootForm.passProductDetails(strProductName, strProductDescription); //Forms.inDepthScootForm.Hide(); // GetDatafrom the inDepthScootForm //Dispose //set it null

Comment: my main aim is to hide the first form as it still lingers in the background as I open the second form.

Comment: Ok so it's look like more a navigation front design. Opening a new window is required ? If its not you could handle in the same Window.